# Sending apache logs to remote rsyslog server adds extra space

Tags: linux, logging, apache2, rsyslog, awstats

I'm trying to send Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) logs to remote rsyslogd  8.2001.0 (aka 2020.01) server and then use awstats 7.6 (build 20161204). I have problem with format and awstats shows that lines a corrupted I'm guessing that lines corrupted because of one extra white space in the beginning. Can someone tell me why rsyslog adds this extra space or how to remove it ? Log looks like:

```
  x.x.x.x - - [06/Jan/2022:08:39:07 +0200] "GET /1.php HTTP/1.1" 200 2906 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/97.0.4692.71 Safari/537.36"
```

But should look like:

```
x.x.x.x - - [06/Jan/2022:08:39:07 +0200] "GET /1.php HTTP/1.1" 200 2906 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/97.0.4692.71 Safari/537.36"
```

My apache config to send logs to local7:

```
CustomLog "| /bin/bash -c /usr/bin/tee -a ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access-my.domain.log | /usr/bin/logger -t my.domain.com -p local7.info" combined
```

Sender rsyslog config:

```
$ModLoad imfile
$InputFilePollInterval 10
$InputFileName  /var/log/apache2/access-*.log
$InputFileTag apache2-access
$InputFileStateFile stat-apache-access
$InputFileSeverity info
$InputRunFileMonitor
$InputFileFacility local7
local7.*        @x.x.x.x
```

Receiver rsyslog:

```
module(load="imudp")
input(type="imudp" port="514")
$template mydomain, "/var/log/remote-logs/access-my.domain.com.log"
$template mydomain2, "%msg%\n"
if $syslogtag == "my.domain.com:" then ?mydomain;mydomain2
& stop
```

Please help, and if you know this is extra: Apache should log to local7 and keep files locally, but this CustomLog only sends to local7 without saving files locally, i know this is OLD (DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS"), that's why I sending logs to remote server , because in this distro no more packages for awstats and Perl modules.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

for white space i need to strip log with

```
"%msg:2:$%\n" not only "%msg%\n"
```

But i have problem why logs not saving locally ?

Comment: You haven't declared any local target where your logs should be saved. In your "sender" config, just add `local7.*         /var/log/local7.log` or wherever you want them to be stored. But your logs should already be in local7, if you're receiving them on your syslog server.

Comment: i do not need save logs in rsyslog server , I talking about locally saving logs,
/bin/bash -c /usr/bin/tee -a ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access-my.domain.log this command seems not working, to remote server all fine, but locally no

Comment: Yes, i understand that and like i wrote, i meant LOCAL TARGET. You have to either define a general target or set up some rules, so rsyslog knows where to log your messages LOCALLY.

Comment: @eDonkey again i repeat this command in httpd.conf "/bin/bash -c /usr/bin/tee -a ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access-my.domain.log" should save logs locally, but doesn't matter anymore because I figured out by my self.. Just created two CustomLog commands in httpd.conf and its worked for me